# How to determine mongodb data file version?

Tags: mongodb

I install mongodb by package installer, but somehow upgraded mongodb.
Now I cannot start mongodb with old data files.

How can I find out with mongodb version created my data files?

Comment: please provide more details.

Comment: If I only have mongodb data files, how can I find out which version of mangodb created it from?

Comment: As I know, mongodb keep the backaward compatability quite well, I do not think data files changed after upgration. I am not sure, BTW

Comment: @DavidBrook, if exists, check your `mogod.log` file startup messages to  check the mongodb version.